# My program doesn't check if there's a duplicate inside a string correctly

Tags: python

I have to do a program that check if there's a duplicate digit inside a 4 number string.
The problem is that like 80% of the times the program classifies as not valid also number which aren't wrong.

```
import random
def extraction():
    random_number = str(random.randint(1000,9999))
    print(random_number)
    for number in random_number:
        n = 0
        print("number1 ",number)
        for number2 in random_number:
            print("number2 ",number2)
            if(number == number2):
                n = n + 1
                print("n ",n)
                if(n == 2):
                    print("The extracted number is not valid.\n")
                    extraction()
```

Comment: Most of that code seems to be irrelevant to your question. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Which parts of that code do the testing? Also, please give and example value that gets the wrong result.

Comment: @RoryDaulton which part of the code do you find extraneous?  It seems to be the right code.  Granted his question is not very explicit, but I don't see any code that doesn't relate to his question.

Comment: I think a solid 50% of S.O. users have the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link as their desktop background :( sometimes it's just easier to help people out...

Comment: I highly suspect that this will just blindly flag all random_numbers as invalid, because you're not considering when number and number2 are both the first digit of the random number, or the second digit, etc... So, on your first iteration of the innermost loop with e.g. "1234" - both number and number2 will be "1"...

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you make a `set()` out of the number string and evaluate the length of the set? If there are duplicate digits, only one entry will be stored in the set

```
if len(set(str(random_number))) == 4:
   pass #you have 4 unique digits
```

Example of working principle:

```
>>> set('1234')
set(['1', '3', '2', '4'])
>>> set('1123')
set(['1', '3', '2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `str.count()` function?

```
def extraction():
    random_number = str(random.randint(1000,9999))
    print(random_number)
    if any([random_number.count(i)>1 for i in random_number]):
        print("The extracted number is not valid.\n")
        extraction()
```